# Graphs in a Facebook App

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook, graph, fbml

I've been messing around a bit with a Facebook application for a while now, which is using FBML. A need has arisen to integrate graphs to display data. From what I can tell my options would be one of the following:

1. Find a Flash Graph that doesn't require a JavaScript library to work
2. Convert the application to an IFrame application, and hope that Facebook wont break the Graph JavaScript
3. Generate the graph serverside with GD or ImageMagick

I would preferably not go with option 3, due to how boring generated graphs look, and serverside load.

Does anyone have any opinions or suggestions on how I would best solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered trying the [google charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?  [image]

You just pass the variables and labels on the query string and google spits back the image.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?

It requires neither flash nor javascript, you just add an image, and the data goes into the url.

Comment: Somehow I have completely missed the existence of Google Charts, definitely looks like the best option so far.